# Android Firebase RecycleView updating incorrecly after item deletion

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have a FirebaseRecycleAdapter. When I populate the Viewholder it should check if there are any entries. If not it show, a TextView that says something in the lines of "you dont have any entries". My problem is that once I delete an item. It quickly flashes the 'empty text' TextView even if there are still other entries in the list. If I delete the last item from the list, it just switches to the 'empty text' TextView even though there are still items on the list.
Perhaps I am not updating the view correctly? Or perhaps I am 'flipping' the view incorrectly ?

Here is my code responsible for the bugs in above text:

```
@Override
protected void populateViewHolder(final NotesViewHolder viewHolder, Notes 
model, final int position) {

final String list_id = getRef(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getKey();

mNotesDatabase.child(list_id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() 
{
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
         if(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() != 0) {
            //'flip' view if dataSnapshot exists
           mFeedList.setVisibility(getItemCount() == 0 ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
           mFapButton.setVisibility(getItemCount() == 0 ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
           tanukisan.setVisibility(getItemCount() == 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
           headText.setVisibility(getItemCount() == 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
           subText.setVisibility(getItemCount() == 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
           seperator.setVisibility(getItemCount() == 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
           emptyNewBtn.setVisibility(getItemCount() == 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
         }
            //not important stuff here 

           viewHolder.mView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
               @Override
               public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                   new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                           .setTitle("Are you sure?")
                           .setMessage("Do you want to delete this note?")
                           .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                               @Override
                               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                   mNotesDatabase.child(list_id).removeValue();
                                   notifyDataSetChanged();
                               }
                           })
                           .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                           .show();

                   return true;
               }
           });
       }

        //'flip' view if dataSnapshot not exists
       else{
         if(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() == 0) {
           mFeedList.setVisibility(getItemCount() == 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
           mFapButton.setVisibility(getItemCount() == 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
           tanukisan.setVisibility(getItemCount() == 0 ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
           headText.setVisibility(getItemCount() == 0 ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
           subText.setVisibility(getItemCount() == 0 ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
           seperator.setVisibility(getItemCount() == 0 ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
           emptyNewBtn.setVisibility(getItemCount() == 0 ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
         }
       }
   }        
    //not implemented functions here 
});
```

Comment: What `DatabaseReference` are you passing to your `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`? And what's the value of `list_id` ?

Comment: try removing   notifyDataSetChanged(); from onClick listner

Comment: If I remove `notifyDataSetChanged();` and I proceed to delete an item, its switches to the other view what so ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you have attached the listener on a single list item `mNotesDatabase.child(list_id)` and when you delete it, it make sense to display that TextView. To solve this, you need to attach a listener a step higher in your tree, loop throught the childrens and then check the children for existens using the following line of code:

```
if(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() == 0) {
    //Display the TextView
} else {
    //Hide the TextView
}
```

Below an example:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference itemsRef = rootRef.child("items");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() != 0) {
            //Hide the TextView
        } else {
            //Display the TextView      
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
itemsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

As you see, the listener is attached on `items` node and not on `items\itemId`.

Comment: I updated my question with above code, but I still have the same problem. Am I implementing your answer wrong ?

Comment: Yes, you are implementing it wrong. You have still the listener attached on a single item. As I said, attach the listener a step higher in your tree and loop  throught the childrens using `getChildren()` method and then use `getChildrenCount()`.

Comment: Everything seems to be working, sorry that I forgot to answer you. Marked the answer as accepted. Cheers!